# How to access arrays or elements of a jagged array one by one?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, jagged-arrays

I have a jagged array where each array contains a waypoint system. The players move throughout a branched map of connected waypoint systems so that when they arrive to an intersection, they can choose a waypoint system 'path' to move through it.

This is my code:

In a serializable script I have one dimension of the array:

```
public Transform[] Array;

public TransformSquareArray(Transform[] array)
{
    Array = array;
}
```

And in another class the jagged array with their correspondent arrays:

```
public TransformSquareArray[] squarepointSystems = new TransformSquareArray[]
{

    new TransformSquareArray(new Transform[0]),
    new TransformSquareArray(new Transform[1]),
    new TransformSquareArray(new Transform[2]),
    new TransformSquareArray(new Transform[3]),
    new TransformSquareArray(new Transform[4]),
    new TransformSquareArray(new Transform[5]),
    new TransformSquareArray(new Transform[6])
};
```

In this way I can edit in the Unity3d inspector how many gameobjects are in each array. Now I want to access in each array in that way that I can edit the 'transform' of the players so they can 'jump' in each array to move in them. At first, I thought about make a series of 'transform' variables, each one containing each array of the jagged, but I can't do that, either because I'm not doing it in the proper way or because I failed with the syntax.But because neither of the arrays has a name so I tried to do this (only one array, as an example):

```
 Transform[] firstRoute = squarepointSystems(new Transform[0]);
```

I doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You reference a public variable, squarepointSystems, which is an array of TransformSquareArray, as a method invocation: squarepointSystems(new Transform[0]). I'm unsure what your intent with the code actually is but things might get cleared up via disambiguation. Here's a crack at that, and see the highlight for the compiler's error (which is the same as mine):

[image]

So I think you are mistaken about what your code is attempting do and getting your classes/variables mixed up.